# Why Monero address is converted to base 58 in blocks, instead of all at once?

Tags: address

I realize that the public address, which is 69 byte, is converted to base 58, but is not converted as a one large number, but rather each 8 bytes are converted separately.
What's the motivation for that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The base58 encoding used in Bitcoin converts all the data to an integer, and then encodes it using divisions by 58. If there is a lot of data, the integer will get very big, which requires having a library dealing with bignums. And usually bignum operations (in this case bignum divisions) are not very fast.

Encoding the data by blocks of 8 bytes at most is much faster because you only have to manage 64-bit integer (a 64-bit integer division will be a single instruction on a 64-bit CPU).

It also allows knowing easily what the size of the encoded string or decoded data will be:

- 8 bytes of data <=> 11 base58 characters
- 7 bytes of data <=> 10 base58 characters
- 6 bytes of data <=> 9 base58 characters
- 5 bytes of data <=> 7 base58 characters
- 4 bytes of data <=> 6 base58 characters
- 3 bytes of data <=> 5 base58 characters
- 2 bytes of data <=> 3 base58 characters
- 1 byte of data <=> 2 base58 characters